# Terraform Kubernetes Server Version

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

Is there a way to get Kubernetes Server Version in [Terraform Kubernetes provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs)? I would like to have the same information provided by `kubectl version` or `kubectl version --short` with Major and Minor server versions.

Comment: You probably can, by using `null_resource` or `terraform_data`.

Comment: why not call the cloud provider directly to to retrieve the version like using the aws_eks_cluster data source? I don't see any data source in the provider that can return that data.

Answer (score -1):

[**External data source**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/external) blocks in Terraform will come in handy for this case. External data source allows users to execute a piece of code or commands of external sources such as python, databases or bash etc.

This is the example block taken from the official terraform documentation use it for reference

```
data "external" "example" {
  program = ["python", "${path.module}/example-data-source.py"]

  query = {
    # arbitrary map from strings to strings, passed
    # to the external program as the data query.
    id = "abc123"
  }
}
```

In the above snippet you can replace the python script with shell script and write your kubernetes commands inside the script and make sure to give executable permissions to the script.

Comment: I know what an external data source is, and this is not a solution since I explicitly asked for the Terraform Kubernetes provider... If I would use something different I can just use a `kubectl` provider which gives me the same information, but it is not the official terraform k8s provider...

Comment: As you said there is no official reference available as of now, it might be a less used functionality. If you want this as a part of your implementation you can raise a [feature request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues) with terraform

Comment: There is an open issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/2196) with relative pull request.